# how to add PHP tags inside java script file

Tags: php, javascript

i have a set of JavaScript files in /js directory.
how to add PHP tags to Javascript File ?

Comment: why do require php tags? kindly post code where you have stuck

Comment: possible duplicate of [php tags in .js file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821711/php-tags-in-js-file)

Comment: i have to add the csrf token name and value in the ajax request that the java script make !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly the same way you add them to any other text file. Open them in a text editor and start typing `<?php etc`.

You need to make sure that PHP is used to process the files though. That is done, most easily, on most systems, by renaming them to have a `.php` file extension. You can also change your webserver's configuration.

If they are going to emit JavaScript, then you should make sure that they claim to be JavaScript, and not HTML (the default for PHP).

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
?>
```

It is typical that JavaScript files are sent with cache control headers that encourage heavy caching. If you add dynamic content to them, then be prepared to lose the benefits of that caching. If appropriate, use PHP to send [suitable cache control headers](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) with the JS.

You may wish to consider keeping your logic in static JavaScript files and use PHP to just inject some dynamic data into a `<script>` element directly into the HTML document.

Answer (score 2):

In Your htaccess file put:

If the  Server has php5 installed use:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .js
```

If the  Server has php4 installed use:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php4 .js
```

If you want to parse a single file you can follow following code in .htaccess.

```
<FilesMatch “testfilename.js”>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .js
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just by adding the .php extension to the javascript file, and you might need to set the header so the browser recognizes the file as a javascript file. You can even pass variables and everything. Ex.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/somefile.js.php?var=hiAgain"></script>
....
```

js/somefile.js.php

```
<?PHP header("Content-type: application/x-javascript"); ?>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("<?PHP echo "Hello from PHP. var:".$GET_['var']; ?>");
})
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.